# Reading STL files in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, stage3d

Has a library been released to read .STL files in AS3? It seems to be a common 3d file and i have yet to find any hope in outputting an .STL file in Stage3d.

Comment: maybe this post can help you: http://automatedchaos.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/ar/

Comment: Ive seen this one. I couldnt find the FLARToolKit STL support. Im going to look a bit more into it. Otherwise this might be promising : http://forum.alternativaplatform.com/posts/list/2792.page

Comment: yeah that link you posted looks more promising than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written just the library you were looking for. You can find it at https://github.com/pranavh/AS3STLViewer

It uses [Away3D](http://away3d.com) to display the parsed stl file.

Hope you like it.